# Angular JS loading issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the following [Angular-Spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) working in my project:

I am trying to get it working with http.get calls. So far I have:

in controllers:

```
$scope.loading = true;
$http.get('js/data/test.json').success(function(results){
$scope.section = results.section;
$scope.loading = false;

});
```

In the view:

```
<span us-spinner="{radius:15, width:4, length: 8}" ng-show="loading"></span>
<div ng-repeat="post in section" class="inner"></div>
```

Currently the loading shows very fast, I want to know is this the correct way to use it? How can I delay it slightly before all the data loads and a spinner is shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a timeout:

```
$scope.loading = true;

setTimeout(function () {
    $http.get('js/data/test.json').success(function(results){
        $scope.section = results.section;
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
}, 5000);
```

This will wait 5 seconds before trying to retrieve the data from the JSON file.

EDIT:
use the $timeout service from Angular. Don't forget to include it in your controller! (Thank you Walfrat)

```
$timeout(function () {
    $http.get('js/data/test.json').success(function(results){
        $scope.section = results.section;
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: even better : use $timeout of angular.

Comment: Of course, delaying a data load for 5 seconds for no real reason is... questionable at best.

Comment: @ deceze, I dont want to delay it 5 seconds but if you look at the original question the data is coming through too quick whether I am using it correct or not

Comment: @rob Yeah, I'm not sure what you're asking exactly in the first place. You're saying the spinner never really shows up because the data is loaded too fast? Well... that's a good problem to have, I'd think...?

Comment: Can you try to elaborate? I think I answered your question perfectly; at least I think I interpreted it correctly.